# BuddyPress Activity Stream - Remove/Replace [...] from blog post excerpts

Tags: buddypress

I'm looking for a way to remove or replace [...] at the end of blog post excerpts on the Activity Stream. I've found a way to replace [...] on the blog page by using the following code.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

excerpt_more is a WordPress filter. It helps with the blog page, but not the BuddyPress Activity Stream.

I found another filter, bp_get_activity_content_body but so far I haven't been able to make the filter do what I want it to do.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What BuddyPress filter can I use to remove or replace [...] on the Activity Stream?

Thx!

Comment: Bump  - I'm still looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

After 6 months of searching I finally got it!!!!

Plugins > BuddyPress > BP-Core > BP-Core-Template.php

Line 875

`'ending' => __( ' [&hellip;]', 'buddypress' ),`

Change `[&hellip;]` to whatever you'd like and then create a new blog post. The new blog post will include the updated text you just entered. Hells yeah!

`[&hellip;]` is the same thing as typing […]

Hollar if this helped you too!!!